# Some questions for bluetooth low energy as an indoor proximity sensor for building or school campus

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

My professor recently approved our research paper which will also be used in our final year thesis. Basically our main purpose is to create a system for location tracking and attendance automation for students and staffs. We would like to use the power of bluetooth low energy modules for this project.
I have actually done quite few research about this but I am having trouble which keywords to use in order for me to filter the right answers for my question. So instead, I'll just put all my questions here.

I provided an image to further understand the concept I am talking about.
Basically, the broadcaster/advertisement mode modules are for students and staffs. While the observer mode modules are initially installed in every rooms or spaces in our building/campus.
[Broadcast and Observer mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5bep.png)

I would like to clarify first that the location tracking is only basic, it only detects which rooms are the students and staffs located.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the maximum advertisement/broadcaster module can the observer module detects at the same time?
2. Our target is about 50 students per room, 300 students in cafeteria, will the observer module have a large amount of latency upon scanning advertisement packets?
3. Do we have to use different module for observer mode, or will the same module for broadcaster mode be just fine?
4. Since this is supposedly embedded to school IDs, we would like to use a coin cell battery, how long will it last?
5. According to my research, BLE range is about 100 meters, but we will be using coin cell battery, is it really possible to achieve 100m for broadcasting and observing? If it is, can we perhaps decrease it by programming?

My apologies for too much question, as this is actually our first time doing applied hardware stuffs due to pandemic. Most of our laboratories are basically tinkercad base. Face-to-face classes are allowed for only medical students for now.

Comment: I don’t think StackOverflow is the right place to ask these questions, even if you get answer(s) - please read [ask]. Voted to close as needs more focus.

Comment: My apologies, I will try to improve the way I ask next time!

Answer (score 1):

A few answers:

- BLE scanners can detect hundreds of distinct broadcasters at the same time.  There is no hard limit, but the more broadcasters the longer it will take the scanners to detect each broadcaster.
- Most BLE modules support both peripheral mode (broadcaster) and central mode (scanner) simultaneously.
- Scanning 50 broadcasters in a single room will easily detect 90% of packets, so if the advertiser is going at 1 Hz it will usually take one second to detect, but sometimes 2-3 seconds of packets are missed.
- The indoor range is closer to 40 meters with no walls obstructing the signal.  Outdoors with clear line of sight the range is higher.  Walls often block signals almost entirely, depending on materials.
- A CR2032 coin cell can power a BLE broadcast at 1 Hz and max power for about 30 days.

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is really helpful and made it clearer for me. My apologies for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an embedded solution is cool and valid but just remember that broadcasters already exists as each and every student carries a smartphone with BLE embedded into it and your observer can be any BLE capable device from smartphone through PC with BLE dongle all the way to Arduino and alike.

Your broadcasters (or BLE peripherals as they should be called) will need an Android / iOS app and you will have to deal with working in the background without the operating system stopping your app.

Your observer (or Central in BLE language) can be any stationary PC if such exists in the class which can make development and deployment a lot easier.

Comment: I do agree about the BLE broadcaster being embedded to our phone and it could make our life easier for our thesis. But unfortunately, our professor would not accept it as a thesis prototype if we do not implement enough hardware stuffs in our thesis. It was already in my mind since the beginning, it's just that they would not allow us to do so. But still thanks for the input! ;)

Comment: Just to cover all options, you can also use BLE Peripheral of your own and student's smartphone as Central to pick up the signal and send identity plus GPS location to a server of your choice. The phone can also pick up signals from stationary BLE Peripherals that you can place in different locations to get an exact indoor location.